# Захват видеопотока окон компьютера, с помощью python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, numpy

Есть программа для захвата части экрана, где `mss` получает изображение с экрана, а `numpy` и `opencv` его обрабатывают.
Нужно получить окно приложения, а не захватывать часть экрана с приложением (в таком случае, если окно будет перекрыто другим, то ничего не изменится).
Есть ли библиотеки, работающие с окнами на python? (под windows, но кроссплатформенные ещё лучше)

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from mss import mss


def nothing(x):
    pass


lim = 2048
name = "Borders"

cv.namedWindow(name)
cv.createTrackbar("top", name, 0, lim, nothing)
cv.createTrackbar("left", name, 0, lim, nothing)
cv.createTrackbar("w", name, 1, lim, nothing)
cv.createTrackbar("h", name, 1, lim, nothing)

sct = mss()


while 1:
    frame = np.array(sct.grab(dict(
        top=cv.getTrackbarPos("top", name),
        left=cv.getTrackbarPos("left", name),
        width=cv.getTrackbarPos("w", name) or 1,
        height=cv.getTrackbarPos("h", name) or 1)))

    cv.imshow("frame", frame)

    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord("1"):
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
        break

sct.close()
```

Comment: вроде, в pywin32 есть инструменты для  захвата окон